# Mocking inherited class where new object is created or how to unsmell my class

Tags: php, unit-testing, design-patterns, phpunit, mockery

Sorry for the messy title, I am trying to add Unit Tests to my (probably) smelly codebase.
I have the something like the following class:

```
namespace App\Service;

use App\Messages\ItemMessage;
use App\Messages\LocationMessage;
use App\Messages\Message;
use App\Settings\Settings;

class MassMessenger
{
    protected static function sendMessagesForDay (int $day, string $content, string $title, Message $messageType): void
    {
        $posts = \App\Repository\Post::getPostForDay($day);
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $message = new $messageType($post->getId(), $content, $title);
            $message->triggerMail();
        }
    }

    public static function sendItem (int $day, Settings $settings): void
    {
        $messageType = new ItemMessage(0, '', '');
        self::sendMessagesForDay($day, $settings->getEmailContent(), $settings->getEmailTitle(), $messageType );
    }

    public static function sendLocation (int $day, Settings $settings): void
    {
        $messageType = new LocationMessage(0, '', '');
        self::sendMessagesForDay($day, $settings->getEmailContent(), $settings->getEmailTitle(), $messageType );
    }
}
```

The Message class is an abstract class that LocationMessage and ItemMessage inherit from.
I want to test the public methods, I do not care too much for mocking the Repository so it is not a completely clean unit test. I also, however do not want to create an integration test where I ask the PHPMailer if the message went through.

So now I am in kind of a pickle on how to design these tests, I tried my hand at this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Service;

use App\Messages\ItemMessage;
use App\Service\MassMessenger;
use App\Settings\Settings;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MassMessengerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSendItem()
    {
        $day = 1;
        $settings = $this->createMock(Settings::class);
        $settings->method('getEmailContent')->willReturn('Test Content');
        $settings->method('getEmailTitle')->willReturn('Test Title');

        $messageMock = \Mockery::mock( ItemMessage::class);
        $messageMock->shouldReceive('triggerMail')->once();
        MassMessenger::sendItem($day, $settings);

        // The test will fail if triggerMail is not called
    }


    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        \Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

it (of course) does not detect the mock, probably because I am doing nothing with it

`Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException : Method triggerMail(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_App_Messages_ItemMessage should be called`

and when I overload the class (like mocking a hard dependency) I get this error:
`TypeError : App\Service\MassMessenger::sendMessagesForDay(): Argument #4 ($messageType) must be of type App\Messages\Message, App\Messages\ItemMessage given, called in /xxx/src/Service/MassMessenger.php on line 24`

Also, I am open to hear any suggestions how I could unsmell my code, I am still learning software design patterns but haven't found the right pattern to create code that is well testable here.

I have also tried to directly test the sendMessagesForDay function by mocking the Message dependency which created worked in isolation but with the other tests but this failed with

`Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock App\Messages\Message, class already exists`

and adding

```
* @runInSeparateProcess
* @preserveGlobalState disabled
```

just made the test fail silently. I am thinking that I have these issues because sendMessage creates a new instance of the mocked object. And since it was already so hard to test this I think I might be better off refactoring the class to make it testable better.

Any advice is highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To "unsmell" and make the class unit testable, you should be using dependency injection for the required classes rather than calling static methods on them.
I don't know whether it would make more sense in your application to inject the dependencies when creating the `MassMessenger` class, or inject them to each of the static methods.

The first example could look like (this is untested)

```
class MassMessenger
{
    protected $post;
    protected $itemMessage;
    protected $locationMessage;
    public function __construct($post, $itemMessage, $locationMessage = null)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->itemMessage = $itemMessage;
        $this->locationMessage = $locationMessage;
    }
 
    protected function sendMessagesForDay (int $day, string $content, string $title, Message $message): void
    {
        $posts = $post->getPostForDay($day);
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $message->triggerMail($post->getId(), $content, $title);
        }
    }

    public function sendItem (int $day, Settings $settings): void
    {
        $this->sendMessagesForDay($day, $settings->getEmailContent(), $settings->getEmailTitle(), $this->itemMessage );
    }

    public function sendLocation (int $day, Settings $settings): void
    {
        $this->sendMessagesForDay($day, $settings->getEmailContent(), $settings->getEmailTitle(), $this->locationMessage );
    }
}
```

Then your test could look like

```
class MassMessengerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSendItem()
    {
        $day = 1;
        $settings = $this->createMock(Settings::class);
        $settings->method('getEmailContent')->willReturn('Test Content');
        $settings->method('getEmailTitle')->willReturn('Test Title');

        $messageMock = \Mockery::mock( ItemMessage::class);
        $messageMock->shouldReceive('triggerMail')->once();
        $messenger = new MassMessenger($post, $messageMock);
        $messenger->sendItem($day, $settings);

        // The test will fail if triggerMail is not called
    }


    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        \Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

In general

- calling static methods in functions makes them harder to test
- instantiating objects in functions makes them harder to test

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
The issue is, that the way the Message class is built it requires a new object of a message for every different post. This is because a lot of initialization is done in the constructor of the message class. This means, that the triggerMail function cannot be called with the postID as a parameter without major changes to the Message class.